# Extract scientific number from string in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to extract scientific numbers from string. Something like:

String str = "Name of value 1.111E-11   Next Name= 444.4";

I want result like:
Result: [1.111E-11, 444.4]

Please suggest better solution for it.

Comment: Please show some effort before asking a question. What have you tried? Why didn't it work? Post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

You can use scanner for this:

```
String str = "Name of value 1.111E-11 Next Name= 444.4";

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(str);

while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    if (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
        System.out.println(scanner.nextDouble());
    } else {
        scanner.next();
    }
}
```

will print:

```
1.111E-11
444.4
```

Scanner by default uses blank spaces delimiter - it means that it reads the words. `next()` returns the next word as String, `nextDouble()` gets next word and tries to parse it to double, so it will throw an exception if word is not a number. That's why the example above uses `hasNextDouble()` to check if the next word is a number, if not it just calls `next()` and ignores the result.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the below regex also.

```
String s = "Name of value 1.111E-11 Next Name= 444.4";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\S)\\d\\S*").matcher(s);
while(m.find())
{
System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

**Output:**

```
1.111E-11
444.4
```